# add strings from one file to another when they have a common column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two file types containing for example: 
file type1 (Hsrr610_mult_notab.ko):

```
K00002 2023649
K00002 2643896
K00006 1614154
K00006 600734
K00008 1562227
K00012 1353687
```

file type2 (Hsrr610.out (extracted from multiple ko_*.ko files)):

```
K00002 ko00010,ko00040,ko00561,ko00930,ko01100,ko01110,ko01120,ko01130,ko01220
K00006 ko00564,ko01110,ko04011
K00008 ko00040,ko00051,ko01100
K00012 ko00040,ko00053,ko00520,ko01100
```

here's the script I wrote to check if there's a common KXXXXX in first and second file append koXXXXX strings (koXXXXX and comma should assume as a single string) to the first file like:

```
K00002 2023649 ko00010,ko00040,ko00561,ko00930,ko01100,ko01110,ko01120,ko01130,ko01220
K00002 2643896 ko00010,ko00040,ko00561,ko00930,ko01100,ko01110,ko01120,ko01130,ko01220
K00006 1614154 ko00564,ko01110,ko04011
K00006 600734 ko00564,ko01110,ko04011
K00008 1562227 ko00040,ko00051,ko01100
K00012 1353687 ko00040,ko00053,ko00520,ko01100
```

, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for i in ko_*.ko
do
r="$(echo $i | sed s/ko_// | sed s/.ko// )";
echo $(echo "$r " && cat $i | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' ) > $r.csvt
done
cat *.csvt > Hsrr610.out && rm *.csvt
for j in $(cat Hsrr610.out)
do 
k="$(echo $j | grep "K[0-9]*" | sed s/\n/0/g | sed s/\t//g)" 
l="$(echo $j | grep "ko*")" 
echo $k
awk -v one="$k" -v two=" $j" '{if (/one/) {$0=$0  two}; print}' Hsrr610_mult_notab.ko > out
done
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As OP changed requirement so adding this solution now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next} {print $0,a[$1]}' Hsrr610.out Hsrr610_mult_notab.ko
```

---

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '!b[$1]++{c[++count]=$1} {a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print c[i] FS a[c[i]]}}' OFS=","  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
!b[$1]++{
  c[++count]=$1
}
{
  a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i] FS a[c[i]]}
}
' OFS=","  Input_file
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it really doesn't work for the desired output, I edited the question.

Comment: @shb, added my EDIT solution too now, please check.

Answer (score 2):

if the keys are sorted, that's what `join` is for.

```
$ join file1 file2

K00002 2023649 ko00010,ko00040,ko00561,ko00930,ko01100,ko01110,ko01120,ko01130,ko01220
K00002 2643896 ko00010,ko00040,ko00561,ko00930,ko01100,ko01110,ko01120,ko01130,ko01220
K00006 1614154 ko00564,ko01110,ko04011
K00006 600734 ko00564,ko01110,ko04011
K00008 1562227 ko00040,ko00051,ko01100
K00012 1353687 ko00040,ko00053,ko00520,ko01100
```

Comment: such a brilliant idea!